# When writing to a file, does all the pages in memory map to contiguous disk blocks in the Disk?

Tags: database, database-design, filesystems

I am interested in knowing how the Filesystem actually writes the files to disk? Does it write it in all contiguous blocks and store the starting block# and device# in the file as metadata?
If they are not stored as contiguous blocks (which I think is the case) then how does it determine the disk blocks so that the read times are optimized?

Answer (score 1):

That's entirely filesystem dependent, there is no general answer.

Here's a good presentation: [ext3 on-disk layout](http://www.geeksofpune.in/drupal/files/8058778-ext34talk.pdf) for the EXT3 filesystem. Others might do it similarly, or completely differently. Have a look at [The structure of the Reiser file system](http://homes.cerias.purdue.edu/~florian/reiser/reiserfs.php) for the reiserfs 3.6 layout.

For a rather different approach, look at [XFS on-disk specification](http://maczfs.googlecode.com/files/ZFSOnDiskFormat.pdf).

The [ext2 disk organization](http://www.nongnu.org/ext2-doc/ext2.html#DISK-ORGANISATION) could probably be described as a "classic" way of doing things that could be found in other filesystems (including its successors).

Comment: Are there any common general strategies?

Comment: not really, but the way things are done for ext2 is rather "classic".

Comment: Thanks. Are there any good resources out there to describe how a Database persists it's Btree onto such a filesystem?

Comment: all database engines do it differently (and they don't all use B-trees). The filesystem implementation doesn't matter, that's transparent for all user-level code. Some databases have options to use raw devices as backing store to avoid the filesystem layer altogether. So you'll need to look at specific database engine/storage engine documentation.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is there some good doc to learn about how mysql does it?

Comment: mysql has multiple storage engines, they all do things differently...  I don't have a link.